# Hacer un efecto de calor en 2D Unity

Tags: unity, unity2d

Soy nuevo en esto del lenguaje de shaderlab en Unity sé que necesitaré esto pero no sé que más hacer

```
    Properties {
        _Background ("Background", 2D) = "" {}            //Textura de fondo
        _BackgroundScrollX ("X Offset", float) = 0        //Cambio de fondo
        _BackgroundScrollY ("Y Offset", float) = 0
        _BackgroundScaleX ("X Scale", float) = 1.0        //Zoom de fondo
        _BackgroundScaleY ("Y Scale", float) = 1.0
        _Refraction ("Refraction", float) = 1.0        //Valor de refracción
        _DistortionMap ("Distortion Map", 2D) = "" {}    //distorsión
        _DistortionScrollX ("X Offset", float) = 0    
        _DistortionScrollY ("Y Offset", float) = 0    
        _DistortionScaleX ("X Scale", float) = 1.0
        _DistortionScaleY ("Y Scale", float) = 1.0
        _DistortionPower ("Distortion Power", float) = 0.08
    }
```

Comment: Bienvenido, revisa por favor [ask],saludos.